# Getting Serial Port Information

Tags: c#, sorting, combobox, serial-port

I have some code that loads the serial ports into a combo-box:

```
     List<String> tList = new List<String>(); 

     comboBoxComPort.Items.Clear();

     foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
     {
        tList.Add(s);
     }

     tList.Sort();
     comboBoxComPort.Items.Add("Select COM port...");
     comboBoxComPort.Items.AddRange(tList.ToArray());
     comboBoxComPort.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I would like to add the port descriptions (similar to what are shown for the COM ports in the Device Manager) to the list <strike>and sort the items in the list that are after index 0</strike> (solved: see above snippet).  Does anyone have any suggestions for adding the port descriptions?  I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition (.NET 2.0).  Any thoughts you may have would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378288/c-custom-combobox-sorting

Comment: How about storing the result of SerialPort.GetPortNames() in a variable, sorting it and then looping.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a [post about this same issue on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdesigner/thread/c236cac4-a954-4a70-882d-bc20e2cc6e81):

> **Getting more information about a serial port in C#**
>
> Hi Ravenb,
>
> We can't get the information through the SerialPort type. I don't know why you need this info in your application. However, there's a [solved thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/c53b23a4-12c3-43ba-9127-b74450ab874a/) with the same question as you. You can check out the code there, and see if it can help you.
>
> If you have any further problem, please feel free to let me know.
>
> Best regards,
>   Bruce Zhou

The link in that post goes to this one:

> **How to get more info about port using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort**
>
> You can probably get this info from a WMI query.  Check out [this tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2CC30A64-EA15-4661-8DA4-55BBC145C30E&displaylang=en) to help you find the right code.  Why would you care though?  This is just a detail for a USB emulator, normal serial ports won't have this.  A serial port is simply know by "COMx", nothing more.

Comment: The link to the solved thread had the code I was after. A bit old but it works to get the COM port number from PID&VID. Thanks +1

Comment: Some painfully inexperienced responses in those quotes.  There are lots of obvious reasons to want this info.  If you're having a user pick a port to use you want to show the device name (it's not 1995, so it's not OK to just give a list of COM ports), and if you're working with a specific known device, you can use device info to automatically pick the correct port.

Answer (score 52):

I tried so many solutions on here that didn't work for me, only displaying some of the ports. But the following displayed All of them and their information.

```
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%(COM%'"))
        {
            var portnames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            var ports = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList().Select(p => p["Caption"].ToString());

            var portList = portnames.Select(n => n + " - " + ports.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(n))).ToList();
            
            foreach(string s in portList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me also. The other solutions did not list the port I was looking for...this one did.

Comment: you help me save hours

Comment: This solution works. There is only a small problem in combining the portnames with the description if you have COM ports higher than 9. It connects e.g. COM16 with COM1 because it finds the string 'COM1' in 'COM16'. I fixed it by changing the s.Contains(n) with s.Contains('('+ n + ')')

Comment: This is the only working solution here. Other solution didn't list all ports or thew null pointer exceptions.

Comment: `SELECT * ...` can be replaced with `SELECT Caption ...`, seeing as that's the only property used later on.

Comment: There's a way to do that also in linux?

Answer (score 43):

**EDIT:**  Sorry, I zipped past your question too quick.  I realize now that you're looking for a list with the port name + port description.  I've updated the code accordingly...

Using System.Management, you can query for all the ports, and all the information for each port (just like Device Manager...)

Sample code (make sure to add reference to System.Management):

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO.Ports;        

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
                ("SELECT * FROM WIN32_SerialPort"))
            {
                string[] portnames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
                var ports = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList();
                var tList = (from n in portnames
                            join p in ports on n equals p["DeviceID"].ToString()
                            select n + " - " + p["Caption"]).ToList();

                tList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            }

            // pause program execution to review results...
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

More info here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: What is the point of calling `SerialPort.GetPortNames();` and `join` when you can just use `p["DeviceID"]` from ManagementObject?

Comment: Are you guaranteed fetching only serial ports? If not, how took you collect only serial ports? I'm curious to know...

Comment: It's not showing a usb to serial converted that's connected (it's showing up on device manager)

Comment: This answer is WRONG. Why does it have 44 up-votes??? It is wrong to search FROM WIN32_SerialPort. The other answers here do it correctly by searching FROM Win32_PnPEntity. Your code lists only 2 of my 6 COM ports !!  All USB to RS232 adapter COM ports are completely missing!

Comment: This didn't list all of my active COM ports whereas humudo's answer does.

Comment: "WIN32_SerialPort" doesn't work - it doesn't list any ports at all!

Comment: @Vincent: Keep in mind that this is a 13 year old answer, so the API may have changed in that time, between versions.

Answer (score 35):

Use following code snippet

It gives following output when executed.

```
serial port : Communications Port (COM1)
serial port : Communications Port (COM2)
```

Don't forget to add

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Also add reference to `system.Management` (by default it is not available)

**C#**

```
private void GetSerialPort()
{

    try
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
            "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity"); 

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            if (queryObj["Caption"].ToString().Contains("(COM"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("serial port : {0}", queryObj["Caption"]);
            }

        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show( e.Message);
    }

}
```

**VB**

```
  Private Sub GetAllSerialPortsName()
        Try
            Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity")
            For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
                If InStr(queryObj("Caption"), "(COM") > 0 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("serial port : {0}", queryObj("Caption"))
                End If
            Next
        Catch err As ManagementException
            MsgBox(err.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Update:
You may also check for

```
if (queryObj["Caption"].ToString().StartsWith("serial port"))
```

instead of

```
if (queryObj["Caption"].ToString().Contains("(COM"))
```

Comment: I had to include a null check since my loop was evaluated 82 times with 3 matches. The rest returned null.
if ((queryObj["Caption"] != null) && (queryObj["Caption"].ToString().Contains("(COM")))

Answer (score 21):

None of the answers here satisfies my needs.

The answer from Muno is **wrong** because it lists ONLY the USB ports.

The answer from code4life is **wrong** because it lists all EXCEPT the USB ports. (Nevertheless it has 44 up-votes!!!)

I have an EPSON printer simulation port on my computer which is not listed by any of the answers here. So I had to write my own solution. Additionally I want to display more information than just the caption string. I also need to separate the port name from the description.

My code has been tested on Windows XP, 7, 10 and 11.

The Port Name (like "COM1") must be read from the **registry** because WMI does not give this information for all COM ports (EPSON).

If you use my code you do **not** need `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` anymore. My function returns the same ports, but with additional details. Why did Microsoft not implement such a function into the framework??

```
using System.Management;
using Microsoft.Win32;

using (ManagementClass i_Entity = new ManagementClass("Win32_PnPEntity"))
{
    const String CUR_CTRL = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\";

    foreach (ManagementObject i_Inst in i_Entity.GetInstances())
    {
        Object o_Guid = i_Inst.GetPropertyValue("ClassGuid");
        if (o_Guid == null || o_Guid.ToString().ToUpper() != "{4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}")
            continue; // Skip all devices except device class "PORTS"

        String s_Caption  = i_Inst.GetPropertyValue("Caption")     .ToString();
        String s_Manufact = i_Inst.GetPropertyValue("Manufacturer").ToString();
        String s_DeviceID = i_Inst.GetPropertyValue("PnpDeviceID") .ToString();
        String s_RegEnum  = CUR_CTRL + "Enum\\" + s_DeviceID + "\\Device Parameters";
        String s_RegServ  = CUR_CTRL + "Services\\BTHPORT\\Parameters\\Devices\\";
        String s_PortName = Registry.GetValue(s_RegEnum, "PortName", "").ToString();
        String s_BT_Dir   = null; // Bluetooth port direction
        String s_BT_Dev   = "";   // Bluetooth paired device name
        String s_BT_MAC   = "";   // Bluetooth paired device MAC address

        int s32_Pos = s_Caption.IndexOf(" (COM");
        if (s32_Pos > 0) // remove COM port from description
            s_Caption = s_Caption.Substring(0, s32_Pos);

        Console.WriteLine("Port Name:      " + s_PortName);
        Console.WriteLine("Description:    " + s_Caption);
        Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer:   " + s_Manufact);
        Console.WriteLine("Device ID:      " + s_DeviceID);

        if (s_DeviceID.StartsWith("BTHENUM\\")) // Bluetooth
        {
            s_BT_Dir = "Incoming";

            // "{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}#7445CEA614BC_C00000000"
            String s_UniqueID = Registry.GetValue(s_RegEnum, "Bluetooth_UniqueID", "").ToString();

            String[] s_Split = s_UniqueID.Split('#');
            if (s_Split.Length == 2)
            {
                s_Split = s_Split[1].Split('_');

                // Ignore MAC = "000000000000"
                if (s_Split.Length == 2 && s_Split[0].Trim('0').Length > 0) 
                {
                    s_BT_MAC = s_Split[0]; // 12 digits: "7445CEA614BC"
                    s_BT_Dir = "Outgoing";

                    // Read the Bluetooth device that is paired with the COM port.
                    Object o_BtDevice = Registry.GetValue(s_RegServ + s_BT_MAC, "Name", null);
                    if (o_BtDevice is Byte[])
                        s_BT_Dev = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((Byte[])o_BtDevice);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Port Direction: " + s_BT_Dir);
            Console.WriteLine("Paired Device:  " + s_BT_Dev);
            Console.WriteLine("Device MAC Adr: " + s_BT_MAC);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    }
}
```

I tested the code with a lot of COM ports. This is the Console output:

```
Port Name:      COM29
Description:    CDC Interface (Virtual COM Port) for USB Debug
Manufacturer:   GHI Electronics, LLC
Device ID:      USB\VID_1B9F&PID_F003&MI_01\6&3009671A&0&0001
-----------------------------------
Port Name:      COM28
Description:    Teensy USB Serial
Manufacturer:   PJRC.COM, LLC.
Device ID:      USB\VID_16C0&PID_0483\1256310
-----------------------------------
Port Name:      COM25
Description:    USB-SERIAL CH340
Manufacturer:   wch.cn
Device ID:      USB\VID_1A86&PID_7523\5&2499667D&0&3
-----------------------------------
Port Name:      COM26
Description:    Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port
Manufacturer:   Prolific
Device ID:      USB\VID_067B&PID_2303\5&2499667D&0&4
-----------------------------------
Port Name:      COM1
Description:    Comunications Port
Manufacturer:   (Standard port types)
Device ID:      ACPI\PNP0501\1
-----------------------------------
Port Name:      COM999
Description:    EPSON TM Virtual Port Driver
Manufacturer:   EPSON
Device ID:      ROOT\PORTS\0000
-----------------------------------
Port Name:      COM20
Description:    EPSON COM Emulation USB Port
Manufacturer:   EPSON
Device ID:      ROOT\PORTS\0001
-----------------------------------
Port Name:      COM8
Description:    Standard Serial over Bluetooth link
Manufacturer:   Microsoft
Device ID:      BTHENUM\{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}_VID&0001005D_PID&223B\7&36284202&0&7445CEA614BC_C00000000
Port Direction: Outgoing
Paired Device:  WH-CH510
Device MAC Adr: 7445CEA614BC
-----------------------------------
Port Name:      COM9
Description:    Standard Serial over Bluetooth link
Manufacturer:   Microsoft
Device ID:      BTHENUM\{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}_LOCALMFG&0000\7&36284202&0&000000000000_00000000
Port Direction: Incoming
Paired Device:
Device MAC Adr: 
-----------------------------------
Port Name:      COM30
Description:    Arduino Uno
Manufacturer:   Arduino LLC (www.arduino.cc)
Device ID:      USB\VID_2341&PID_0001\74132343530351F03132
-----------------------------------
```

COM1 is a COM port on the mainboard.

COM 8 and 9 are Buetooth COM ports.

COM 25 and 26 are USB to RS232 adapters.

COM 28 and 29 and 30 are Arduino-like boards.

COM 20 and 999 are EPSON ports.

NOTE: If you get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` when opening a Bluetooth COM port the solution may be remove the device and do the pairing again.

Comment: This is lovely, thank you so much! Also thanks for updating the post after doing more tests.
I used your method with little modifications to identify which COM port a specific HW is connected to via its VID and PID. Works like a charm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 13):

I combined previous answers and used structure of Win32_PnPEntity class which can be found found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-pnpentity).
Got solution like this:

```
using System.Management;
public static void Main()
{
     GetPortInformation();
}

public string GetPortInformation()
    {
        ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_PnPEntity");
        ManagementObjectCollection Ports = processClass.GetInstances();           
        foreach (ManagementObject property in Ports)
        {
            var name = property.GetPropertyValue("Name");               
            if (name != null && name.ToString().Contains("USB") && name.ToString().Contains("COM"))
            {
                var portInfo = new SerialPortInfo(property);
                //Thats all information i got from port.
                //Do whatever you want with this information
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

SerialPortInfo class:

```
public class SerialPortInfo
{
    public SerialPortInfo(ManagementObject property)
    {
        this.Availability = property.GetPropertyValue("Availability") as int? ?? 0;
        this.Caption = property.GetPropertyValue("Caption") as string ?? string.Empty;
        this.ClassGuid = property.GetPropertyValue("ClassGuid") as string ?? string.Empty;
        this.CompatibleID = property.GetPropertyValue("CompatibleID") as string[] ?? new string[] {};
        this.ConfigManagerErrorCode = property.GetPropertyValue("ConfigManagerErrorCode") as int? ?? 0;
        this.ConfigManagerUserConfig = property.GetPropertyValue("ConfigManagerUserConfig") as bool? ?? false;
        this.CreationClassName = property.GetPropertyValue("CreationClassName") as string ?? string.Empty;
        this.Description = property.GetPropertyValue("Description") as string ?? string.Empty;
        this.DeviceID = property.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID") as string ?? string.Empty;
        this.ErrorCleared = property.GetPropertyValue("ErrorCleared") as bool? ?? false;
        this.ErrorDescription = property.GetPropertyValue("ErrorDescription") as string ?? string.Empty;
        this.HardwareID = property.GetPropertyValue("HardwareID") as string[] ?? new string[] { };
        this.InstallDate = property.GetPropertyValue("InstallDate") as DateTime? ?? DateTime.MinValue;
        this.LastErrorCode = property.GetPropertyValue("LastErrorCode") as int? ?? 0;
        this.Manufacturer = property.GetPropertyValue("Manufacturer") as string ?? string.Empty;
        this.Name = property.GetPropertyValue("Name") as string ?? string.Empty;
        this.PNPClass = property.GetPropertyValue("PNPClass") as string ?? string.Empty;
        this.PNPDeviceID = property.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID") as string ?? string.Empty;
        this.PowerManagementCapabilities = property.GetPropertyValue("PowerManagementCapabilities") as int[] ?? new int[] { };
        this.PowerManagementSupported = property.GetPropertyValue("PowerManagementSupported") as bool? ?? false;
        this.Present = property.GetPropertyValue("Present") as bool? ?? false;
        this.Service = property.GetPropertyValue("Service") as string ?? string.Empty;
        this.Status = property.GetPropertyValue("Status") as string ?? string.Empty;
        this.StatusInfo = property.GetPropertyValue("StatusInfo") as int? ?? 0;
        this.SystemCreationClassName = property.GetPropertyValue("SystemCreationClassName") as string ?? string.Empty;
        this.SystemName = property.GetPropertyValue("SystemName") as string ?? string.Empty;
    }

    int Availability;
    string Caption;
    string ClassGuid;
    string[] CompatibleID;
    int ConfigManagerErrorCode;
    bool ConfigManagerUserConfig;
    string CreationClassName;
    string Description;
    string DeviceID;
    bool ErrorCleared;
    string ErrorDescription;
    string[] HardwareID;
    DateTime InstallDate;
    int LastErrorCode;
    string Manufacturer;
    string Name;
    string PNPClass;
    string PNPDeviceID;
    int[] PowerManagementCapabilities;
    bool PowerManagementSupported;
    bool Present;
    string Service;
    string Status;
    int StatusInfo;
    string SystemCreationClassName;
    string SystemName;       

}
```

Comment: Probably the best solution on this page. Apart from being able to filter by other fields, you also get all the other device information you might need.

Comment: If there are many com port devices connected how do we know who is who? I see many devices doesnt have hardwareid at all!!! So there is no way to identify it automatically and we always have to select COM port manualy!!!! (((

Comment: This is definitely the best answer on the page, only addition I made was to add a COMPort property and extract the actual com port value (e.g. COM15) from the caption just to make it easier for use. But an excellence solution.

Comment: This answer is WRONG. Why do you list only the USB ports?? The COM port on my mainboard is omitted by your code. The question does not ask specifically for USB COM ports. Remove that: && name.ToString().Contains("USB")

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "sorting the items after index 0", but if you just want to sort the array of strings returned by `SerialPort.GetPortNames()`, you can use [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwx6zbd4.aspx).

Comment: I've added details to my original question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite Elmue's answer and enrich it using Muno's `SerialPortInfo` class. So it is more clear and provides more information. *(.net 6)*

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Management;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

public static class SerialPortSearcher
{

    [SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
    public static IEnumerable<ISerialPortInfo> Search()
    {
        using var entity = new ManagementClass("Win32_PnPEntity");
        foreach (var instance in entity.GetInstances().Cast<ManagementObject>())
        {
            var classGuid = instance.GetPropertyValue("ClassGuid");
            // Skip all devices except device class "PORTS"
            if (classGuid?.ToString()?.ToUpper() == "{4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}")
            {
                yield return new SerialPortInfo(instance);
            }
        }
    }

    [SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
    private class SerialPortInfo : ISerialPortInfo
    {
        public SerialPortInfo(ManagementObject obj)
        {
            this.Availability = obj.GetPropertyValue("Availability") as int? ?? 0;
            this.Caption = obj.GetPropertyValue("Caption") as string ?? string.Empty;
            this.ClassGuid = obj.GetPropertyValue("ClassGuid") as string ?? string.Empty;
            this.CompatibleID = obj.GetPropertyValue("CompatibleID") as string[] ?? new string[] { };
            this.ConfigManagerErrorCode = obj.GetPropertyValue("ConfigManagerErrorCode") as int? ?? 0;
            this.ConfigManagerUserConfig = obj.GetPropertyValue("ConfigManagerUserConfig") as bool? ?? false;
            this.CreationClassName = obj.GetPropertyValue("CreationClassName") as string ?? string.Empty;
            this.Description = obj.GetPropertyValue("Description") as string ?? string.Empty;
            this.DeviceID = obj.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID") as string ?? string.Empty;
            this.ErrorCleared = obj.GetPropertyValue("ErrorCleared") as bool? ?? false;
            this.ErrorDescription = obj.GetPropertyValue("ErrorDescription") as string ?? string.Empty;
            this.HardwareID = obj.GetPropertyValue("HardwareID") as string[] ?? new string[] { };
            this.InstallDate = obj.GetPropertyValue("InstallDate") as DateTime? ?? DateTime.MinValue;
            this.LastErrorCode = obj.GetPropertyValue("LastErrorCode") as int? ?? 0;
            this.Manufacturer = obj.GetPropertyValue("Manufacturer") as string ?? string.Empty;
            this.Name = obj.GetPropertyValue("Name") as string ?? string.Empty;
            this.PNPClass = obj.GetPropertyValue("PNPClass") as string ?? string.Empty;
            this.PNPDeviceID = obj.GetPropertyValue("PnpDeviceID") as string ?? string.Empty;
            this.PowerManagementCapabilities = obj.GetPropertyValue("PowerManagementCapabilities") as int[] ?? new int[] { };
            this.PowerManagementSupported = obj.GetPropertyValue("PowerManagementSupported") as bool? ?? false;
            this.Present = obj.GetPropertyValue("Present") as bool? ?? false;
            this.Service = obj.GetPropertyValue("Service") as string ?? string.Empty;
            this.Status = obj.GetPropertyValue("Status") as string ?? string.Empty;
            this.StatusInfo = obj.GetPropertyValue("StatusInfo") as int? ?? 0;
            this.SystemCreationClassName = obj.GetPropertyValue("SystemCreationClassName") as string ?? string.Empty;
            this.SystemName = obj.GetPropertyValue("SystemName") as string ?? string.Empty;

            var regPath = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Enum\\" + PNPDeviceID + "\\Device Parameters";
            this.PortName = Registry.GetValue(regPath, "PortName", "")?.ToString();

            //int i = Caption.IndexOf(" (COM");
            //if (i > 0) // remove COM port from description
            //    Caption = Caption.Substring(0, i);

        }

        public int Availability { get; }
        public string Caption { get; }
        public string ClassGuid { get; }
        public string[] CompatibleID { get; }
        public int ConfigManagerErrorCode { get; }
        public bool ConfigManagerUserConfig { get; }
        public string CreationClassName { get; }
        public string Description { get; }
        public string DeviceID { get; }
        public bool ErrorCleared { get; }
        public string ErrorDescription { get; }
        public string[] HardwareID { get; }
        public DateTime InstallDate { get; }
        public int LastErrorCode { get; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; }
        public string Name { get; }
        public string PNPClass { get; }
        public string PNPDeviceID { get; }
        public int[] PowerManagementCapabilities { get; }
        public bool PowerManagementSupported { get; }
        public bool Present { get; }
        public string Service { get; }
        public string Status { get; }
        public int StatusInfo { get; }
        public string SystemCreationClassName { get; }
        public string SystemName { get; }
        public string? PortName { get; }
    }
}

public interface ISerialPortInfo
{
    int Availability { get; }
    string Caption { get; }
    string ClassGuid { get; }
    string[] CompatibleID { get; }
    int ConfigManagerErrorCode { get; }
    bool ConfigManagerUserConfig { get; }
    string CreationClassName { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    string DeviceID { get; }
    bool ErrorCleared { get; }
    string ErrorDescription { get; }
    string[] HardwareID { get; }
    DateTime InstallDate { get; }
    int LastErrorCode { get; }
    string Manufacturer { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string PNPClass { get; }
    string PNPDeviceID { get; }
    string? PortName { get; }
    int[] PowerManagementCapabilities { get; }
    bool PowerManagementSupported { get; }
    bool Present { get; }
    string Service { get; }
    string Status { get; }
    int StatusInfo { get; }
    string SystemCreationClassName { get; }
    string SystemName { get; }
}
```

Test it in `Program.cs`:

```
using System.Text.Json;

var ports = SerialPortSearcher.Search().ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(ports, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

A small change from me, not all ports had descriptions.

```
public static class SerialPortSearcher
    {
        public const string PortsClassGuid = "{4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}";
        public const string ModemClassGuid = "{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}";

        public static IEnumerable<ISerialPortInfo> GetPortInformationYield()
        {
            using (var entity = new ManagementClass("Win32_PnPEntity"))
                foreach (var instance in entity.GetInstances().Cast<ManagementObject>())
                {
                    var classGuid = instance.GetPropertyValue("ClassGuid")?.ToString()?.ToUpper();
                    // Skip all devices except device class "PORTS"
                    if (classGuid == PortsClassGuid || classGuid == ModemClassGuid)
                    {
                        yield return new SerialPortInfo(instance);
                    }
                }
        }

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<ISerialPortInfo>> GetPortInformationAsync()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var portInfos = new List<SerialPortInfo>();

                using (var processClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_PnPEntity"))
                {
                    using (ManagementObjectCollection ports = processClass.GetInstances())
                    {
                        foreach (ManagementObject property in ports.Cast<ManagementObject>())
                        {
                            var classGuid = property.GetPropertyValue("ClassGuid")?.ToString()?.ToUpper();
                            // Skip all devices except device class "PORTS"
                            if (classGuid == PortsClassGuid || classGuid == ModemClassGuid)
                            {
                                portInfos.Add(new SerialPortInfo(property));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return portInfos.AsEnumerable();
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
this.comboPortName.Items.AddRange(
    (from qP in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
     orderby System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(qP, "~\\d",
     string.Empty).PadLeft(6, '0')
     select qP).ToArray()
);
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.