# Is there any way to get information about the device corresponding to a com port?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Within Vb.net I can connect to a device via com port but do not know anything about the corresponding device. Is there any way to programmatically tell which device a particular com port is associated with.

Thanks

Comment: There is no any way to detect whether any device is connected to COM port at all.

Comment: There is some C# code at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837985/getting-serial-port-information) that can retrieve information similar to what Device Manager will display. Are you looking for something more than this?

Answer (score 0):

No. The only way is to send some data and interpret whatever comes back (if anything does come back).

The data you send and receive would be specific the the particular device connected. There is no common standard handshake.