# C# device driver name

Tags: c#, windows

I write some application, in form it has three combobox with serial ports names(com1, com3, com5).
In device manager i see: silicon labs cp210x(com5), moxa uport 1130(com3), serial port(com1).
How i can get these names from my application?

Comment: This is an solved question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837985/getting-serial-port-information

Comment: Note: Should be a duplicate of the above, but it has a link only answer.

Comment: @Sayse Look at the second answer: shows exactly how to do it.

Comment: @Richard - I didn't get any further than the first answer since it kind of raised the valid point of should you really ever need to know this information

Answer (score 0):

Windows Management Infrastructure (WMI) is probably the easiest way: the WMI type [`Win32_SerialPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394413(v=vs.85).aspx).

Make use of the [`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace types to access WMI from .NET applications.