# how do i get specific port of broadband modem

Tags: c#, port, gsm

I'm using gsmcomm library and Huawei GSM modem. The has two ports. if I list the ports and loop to auto connect into it, I'm having a problem connecting to the specific port which is functional to sending message which is the COM6 and COM5 is not the right port. (Image link attach below for more info)

So is there any way to get the whole name of that port? any way to connect to that specific port and avoid the other port?

Please check this image of they show up in the device manager as reference of my question.

[image]

Comment: WMI can enumerate the display captions that exist for USB emulated ports a la Device Manager, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837985/getting-serial-port-information

Comment: why this object wont appear --> ManagementObjectSearcher?
i added using System.Management but still dont appear

Comment: You need to add a reference to System.Management and `using System.Management;`

Comment: thank you. i added it to reference and it works.

Comment: I can't yet fully understand the code. can you help me with the error?

if (queryObj["Caption"].ToString().StartsWith("serial port"))

error:  An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in gsmtest.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Make sure `queryObj["Caption"]` is not null before calling ToString() on it.

Comment: why caption is null? i thought it will get the port description but it null. i check device manager and the port COM6 and COM5 is there but why it is null?

Comment: Seeking for help. it does not return the port that i need.

Comment: Instead of "Caption" try "Description" (still checking for null) A list of possible property names for queryObj[] is here; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: thank you. it works for the description. but how can i include the port name?

description and port name... i can't see option for port name

Comment: Your the best.! your a savior.
My smile reflects at the monitor screen.. thank you sir Alex

Comment: Hi. when it detects 3G application interface, it will not display the 3g pc ui interface(base on the image). only one port it will detect.