# Determining port of specific Numato Relay Board

Tags: python, serial-port, raspbian

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805563/how-to-find-a-serial-port-device-in-net-with-its-driver-name) I am trying to use Python to find a certain relay board on a Raspberry Pi when the port could be switching between /dev/ttyACM0 and /dev/ttyACM1 each time the pi is powered up, I have 2 boards connected to the pi and they can switch back and forth as to which is 0 and which is 1. I am using a Numato 16 channel relay, which comes with an ID that can be get and set on each board, however I am having trouble reading the results. Numato's website says that id get returns an 8 byte string with the id, and elsewhere I read that the return will have a couple of extra characters due to how they concatenate and format their echos and returns.

My script looks like this

```
import serial
request = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 19200, timeout=1)
request.write(b"id get\n\r")
request.read(20)
```

However, instead of getting the result `b'\n\rid get\n\rXXXXXXXX'` I am getting the result `b'\nid get\n\n\r>'`

When I ran with the `'ver'` command I was able to get the results returned properly.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `\n`.

Comment: Or using `\r\n`

Comment: Thanks for the ideas guys, but neither of those worked.

Comment: After letting it sit for a day, and trying again, dropping the \n worked. @JohnnyMopp post this as an answer and I'll accept it.