# C# ComboBox Sorting Issue

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a problem with combobox sorting . 
The combobox sorts numbers (half) correctly
two digit numbers come before one digit number when the tenth digit is smaller that the digit, i mean:

1

11

12

2

how can i change the combox order in a way that it will appear like:

1

2

11

12

[A Combobox image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZAGi.jpg)

Comment: Please, publish combobox filling code

Comment: You are using string instead of int

Comment: what is the datatype of the values? i think it is string in your case

Comment: it is your answer what you want-->
[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1378349/5794451)

Comment: My code (image) :

http://prntscr.com/do1vrh 

And i'm using an int not a string in my database

Comment: You use ToString so you are using strings

Comment: I'm using WinForms , and i tried to remove the ToString  but still it dosen't work

Answer (score 0):

Kfir, try this way, use datasource and do not fill items manually:

```
    private readonly List<int> _list = new List<int>();
    private BindingList<int> _bList;
    private readonly BindingSource _bSource = new BindingSource();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _list.Add(23);
        _list.Add(2);
        _list.Add(5);
        _list.Add(12);
        _list.Add(14);
        _list.Add(8);
        _list.Add(9);
        _list.Add(15);
        _list.Add(21);
        _list.Add(22);
        _list.Add(1);

        _bList = new BindingList<int>(_list);
        _bSource.DataSource = _bList;
        comboBox2.DataSource = _bSource;
        _list.Sort();
        _bList.ResetBindings();
```

Comment: Thank You , but i need to get the values from Access

Comment: OK. You can fill "List<int> _list" from database.